# Generate report pdf in java - swing, table

Tags: java, report

I have a problem with generating a pdf report from my program. I do not know how to do it, I tried with iText, but the error pops up. I have tables created in my program, where I have 4 columns and adds more rows, I would like the program to generate a report from this table after pressing the button.

```
      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tabela.getModel();
        String path="";
        JFileChooser j= new JFileChooser();
       j.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      j.showSaveDialog(this);
          int x=j.showOpenDialog(this);

          if(x==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
 path=j.getSelectedFile().getPath();
 }

 Document doc= new Document();
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream(path+"raport.pdf"));
        doc.open();
        PdfPTable tbl=new PdfPTable(4);
        tbl.addCell("column1");
        tbl.addCell("column2");
        tbl.addCell("column3");
        tbl.addCell("column4");

        for(int i=0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
            String column1=table.getValueAt(i, 0).toString();
            String column2=table.getValueAt(i, 1).toString();
            String column3=table.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
            String column4=table.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();

            tbl.addCell(column1);
            tbl.addCell(column2);
            tbl.addCell(column3);
            tbl.addCell(column4);
        }
         doc.add(tbl);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
    Logger.getLogger(Energy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Energy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: What SDK are you using to render PDFs? What document model are you using? DOM4J, W3C dom?

Comment: I am working on NetBeans, I want to generate it the easiest way. Any of this document.

Comment: The report saves, but an error pops up that the pdf is damaged and can not be opened.

Comment: Thanks buddy, exactly this was doc.close (); :) By the way I will ask you how to add a title over the table and how to add other components from the program not from the table, in the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't forget to call `doc.close();` to close the stream / finish the save.